# How can i make a partition sharable to windows in the given options

Tags: filesystem

I am unable to find my files in D drive of Windows. I have make a partition of that drive in ubuntu which is working properly but not the old one. It's showing some file system error and there is no option to get it back. Please help me to fix it.!
Error is:  The volume does not contain a recognized file system

Comment: You may just need to run chkdsk from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive is working in Ubuntu then copy the data to some other drive then use gparted to format the drive as ntfs(the file system that works with windows and also with Ubuntu).
Maybe you've made the new drive as ext4 so thats why it's not getting detected in windows. Changing it to ntfs may resolve the issue.
Make sure your data is backed up to another drive.

Comment: Bu t I'm unable yo open that drive. It show to formate D drive and properties show nothing. Its the problem of file system recognization. While searching the solution they say to recover that drive and formate it.